# Как правильно сделать такой цикл?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Как сделать так, чтобы если счет у пользователя был меньше нуля после покупки, то покупка отменяется? 
P.s есть наработка самого цикла

```
if($sql >= "0") {echo 'У вас недостаточно средств!';exit();} else {}
```

Код всего файла:

```
<?
if(isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $id = $_GET["id"];
} else{}

if(isset($_GET["us_id"])) {
    $us_id = $_GET["us_id"];
} else{}

include_once'db.php';
include_once'handler.php';

if ($sql >="0") {
    echo'У вас недостаточно денег';
    exit();
} else{}

$prod = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM red_shop WHERE id = '$id'");
$prod = mysql_fetch_array($prod);

$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users_profiles SET quarck = quarck -".$prod['price']." WHERE user_id = ".$us_id." ");
if ($sql) {
    echo'Вы успешно совершили покупку!';
} else {
    echo'Произошла ошибка';
}
echo $id." ".$us_id;?>
```

Но при его выполнении происходит покупка, хотя ошибка выводится.

Comment: Что вы делаете на сэкономленных на форматировании кода строчках? %-0

Comment: ``$sql`` - это что?

Comment: @Эникейщик Запрос к БД, а что?

Comment: Запрос к БД для чего? Что лежит в этой переменной?

Comment: А главное - при какой тут вообще цикл?

Comment: *Как сделать так, чтобы если счет у пользователя был меньше нуля после покупки, то покупка отменяется?* Зачем делать, потом проверять и, возможно, отменять, когда проще сразу сравнить стоимость покупки с остатком средств, и если остаток меньше, то никаких покупок не делать?

Comment: @Akina Можно и так, подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: Сделайте триггер на update таблицы users_profiles, который вернет ошибку если поле quarck станет меньше нуля. такие проверки должны быть не в коде приложения, а на уровне БД, что бы даже при ошибках в приложениях невозможно было увести баланс в минус. Кроме того обратите внимание на: 1. делать select и потом update нет смысла, можно сделать это одним действием. 2. все поля вы подставляете в текст запросов непосредственно, любой начинающий хакер произведет у вас все покупки бесплатно (см. "sql-инъекция"), вернее вы ему еще должны будете

Comment: 3. Вы используете расширение mysql, вместо pdo, в ближайшее время вам будет все труднее и труднее найти хостинг на котором ваш код заработает, потому что эти функции удалены из новых версий php

Comment: А зачем вообще давать купить, если на счету не достаточно средств? Так и отменять ничего не придется.